# Domain Management using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Suppose all the requests on A.com and B.com end up on the same server, and I want to control the request using htaccess.

The default www content root is `/public_html/`, but I want `A.com` requests to be forwarded to `/public_html/A/` and `B.com` requests should be forwarded to `/public_html/B/`

I came up with this solution:

```
#/public_html/.htaccess
# A.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^A.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/A/
RewriteRule (.*) A/$1 [L]

# B.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^B.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/B/
RewriteRule (.*) B/$1 [L]
```

and I am having two problems with it:

1. `A.com/A/index.php` and `A.com/index.php` are the same thing, which is not cool! I'd rather the user be 301-ly redirected to the latter whenever he uses the former.
2. `A.com/etc` redirects to `A.com/A/etc/`

Overall, I don't want my visitors to see the `/A/` (or `/B/`) in the URL anyway. Any htaccess solution is welcome.

Comment: Have you set-up different virtual hosts for `a.com` & `b.com`?

Comment: @ThinkingMonkey: No, My hosting plan doesn't let me to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# for external redirection of A.com/A/foo to A.com/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/*(A|B)(?:/(.*)|)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.com/%2 [R=301,L,NC]

# for internal redirection of A.com/foo to A.com/A/foo
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(A|B)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^(A|B)(?:/(.*)|)$)^.*$ %1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in the same order:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(A|B)(?:/(.*))?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [NC,L,R=301]

#/public_html/.htaccess
# A.com or B.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(A|B).com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) %1/$1 [L]
```

If you do not want `A` to be redirected to `A` when accessed like this `A.com/B/`. or If you do not want `B` to be redirected to `B` when accessed like this `B.com/A/`. You can throw a `404` error.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^A.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/B(?:/(.*))? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^B.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/A(?:/(.*))? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Add the above lines right after`RewriteRule ^ - [L]` before `RewriteRule ^(A|B)(?:/(.*...`.

Comment: Ooops! Now `A.com/etc` is redirected to `A.com/A/etc/` and thus gets 403!

Comment: @SeMeKh The `403` was due to the `F` flag. not because of `A.com/etc` getting redirected to `A.com/A/etc/`. Was done intentionally. Now have changed it to to redirect now.

Comment: Seems like this is not a valid htaccess file, I get Internal Server Error. Also, `A.com/etc` DOES redirect to `A.com/A/etc/` because of trailing slash stuff.